# Why use variables when adding text to the DOM?

Tags: javascript

I am pretty new to web dev and I have been doing some JavaScript exercises I found on line. One of them asks to prompt the user for a first and last name and add these names to the document.

In researching this I found code that used a lot of variables. My solution was this:

```
var el = document.getElementById("welcome");
var txt = fullName;
var node = document.createTextNode(txt);
el.appendChild(node);
    };

greet()
```

I played around a bit, and found that this worked:

```
document.getElementById("welcome").appendChild(document.createTextNode(fullName));
```

You can see my original solution at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mPscp/). I also added the instructions to the HTML.

My question is why do most tuts suggest putting in the variables at all? Is it best practice? Why?

Oh, and if you go there, can someone tell me why my ordered list came out with no numbers? Does jsFiddle use a reset on their CSS?

Note: I'm not sure I needed to put it in a function, but right  now, putting everything in a box helps me keep organized.

Thanks for any help
Dave

Comment: It's best practice to use variables if you're reusing them. If you're using it just once, go ahead and do it on one line if you find it easier, but when you start working with other devs you might find yourself going back to setting variables, and adding comments after them.

Comment: Yes fiddle resets, just uncheck **Normalize CSS** option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not that you need to use many variables in your code, it's just that you are a beginner and often author doesn't use super programming skills to teach beginner's, as and when you learn you can make your code stronger, shorter, and much intelligent. So if you are writing a better code while you are studying that's seems that you are learning much much faster...Using variables to hold values is often a good practice..but ofcourse if you are smart enough to make your work without using much of them is no harm...here's a simple example where you don't actually need 2 variables

```
var a = 5, b = 5;
var result = a + b;

alert(result); //Results 10
```

could be simply written as

```
var total = 5 + 5;
alert(total); //Results 10 too
```

But again when going for the second approach you might not be using `var total` everywhere and you need to change the values yourself everytime you want a result, so better create sufficient variables which will be easier for you to modify your code and use the data accordingly

And for the other question, yes jsfiddle do resets CSS

Just uncheck *Normalized CSS* if you don't want to reset the elements

Answer (score 1):

Variables can "give names" to values. These names - can, but not always - make code more self-descriptive and easier to follow. The variable names in the example are, unfortunately a bad example of good descriptive names, but ..

(consider this instead)

```
var welcomeElm = document.getElementById("welcome");
var titleElm = document.createTextNode(fullname);
welcomeElm.appendChild(titleElm);
// and maybe also do something else too ..
// (no need to re-evaluate getElementById)
welcomeElm.className = "available";
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for the response. I appreciate the input, I am trying to get into good habits!

Answer (score 1):

using variable is good practice if u require "document.getElementById("welcome")" more than once .

it will reduce your page size which will make your page work faster.

Answer (score 1):

Variables are used to store values in your code. If You Use Code Without storing them in a variable then it will be difficult for you to manipulate your data. As in your code, you used prompt. If you does not make it in variable then how can you get the value which user had entered and variables in Javascript helps us to not to write big code and saves our time!

Answer (score 1):

A few reasons to use them, though I doubt any are the case here.

### Self-documenting.

```
var title = "Program crashed";
var msg = "Program crashed";
do_alert(title, msg);
```

### Easier debugging: (Code slightly changed based on comments)

```
var step1 = long_complex_function();
alert(step1);
//console.log(step1);

var step2 = long_other_calcuation;
alert.log(step2);
//console.log(step2);

do_major_func(step1, step2);
```

Comment: He is a beginner, `console.log` will go over his head

Comment: @Mr.Alien yes and i think he even don't know what is console? :P

Comment: @AspiringAqib Ya if someone is a beginner he needs spoon feed, but ofcourse there's a difference..if you've programming experience with other languages you catch things muc faster but somethings always go over beginner's head..imo..